# Wpf. Prism. Взаимодействие элементов в разных регионах

Tags: wpf, prism

Работая с Prism регионами, столкнулся с проблемой взаимподействия элементов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конкретнее.

1. Это RegionMain
2. Какой-то элемент с именем Element

При нажатии на кнопку запускается анимация
Код:

```
<Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="95"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="Element"
                        From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:1"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
```

Если содержимое региона перенести на форму то ошибки не будет и анимация сработает, а если регион оставить вылазит ошибка:

Additional information: Не удается найти имя "Element" в области имен "System.Windows.Controls.Button".

Как запустить анимацию элемента из другого региона?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давайте я попробую привести аналогию. У вас есть локальная переменная в одной функции. Вы разбили эту функцию на две меньшие, локальная переменная осталась в одном куске. Теперь почему-то код в другом куске, ссылающийся на эту самую локальную переменную, перестал работать.

---

Вы делаете неправильно. Вам не должно хотеться из одного куска кода управлять другим.

Положите анимацию к элементу, на котором эта анимация происходит. Раз вы уж пользуетесь Prism, вам не обойти MVVM. А это значит, UI-событиями должны управлять не другие UI-события, а привязанные данные.

Пусть кнопка, как и ей положено, отправляет команду в VM. На этом роль региона с кнопкой заканчивается.

Регион №2 пускай следит за данными, и запускает анимацию, когда нужно. Например, это может быть `DataTrigger`.

Регионы должны взаимодействовать не иначе, как через VM. Этим вы уменьшите связность UI-кода.

Comment: Почему не работает, я понимаю. И я работаю с MVVM. Просто не хватает опыта. Спасибо что подсказали на счет DataTrigger о нем я сразу не подумал.

Comment: А не могли бы Вы подсказать по поводу дочерних окно при работе с Prism

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Я имел в виду аналогией, что и решать надо по идее аналогичным путём.

Comment: @Vyacheslav: С дочерними окнами по идее то же самое: связь через VM.

Comment: Тут вопрос с региона в разных окнах. Т.е. регионы главного окна видны а вот регионы других окон не импортятся

Comment: @Vyacheslav: Ну, всё равно через VM :) У VM есть (должны быть) ссылки друг на друга вне зависимости, их UI в одном окне или нет.